# jHtmlArea not working with jQuery 1.9.1 and above - What to do about it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jhtmlarea

I just found, that using [jHtmlArea](http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/), the nice WYSIWYG text editor, does not work with the newer [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) versions, from 1.9.1 and above.

I have taken most code from the example, but wanted to reference a current jQuery library.

```
<body>

    $(function () {
        $("textarea").htmlarea();
    });

    <textarea id="txtDefaultHtmlArea" cols="50" rows="15">
        <p><h3>Test H3</h3>This is some sample text to test out the <b>WYSIWYG Control</b>.</p>
    </textarea>
</body>
```

I have created a fiddle. Unless I turn on the `Migrate 1.1.0` script, the editor does not show the nicely formatted text area, just the bare HTML and the editor buttons do not work.

Here's how it currently looked like:

[image: JSFiddle showing the result]

I also have reproduced this behavior with an asp.net WebForms page and with local files.

**What can I do about it?** Should I go and try to fix jHtmlArea for me? For other components on the page, I would like to use current jQuery. **Will I get in trouble, when I reference both an old and newer jQuery version on the same page?**

UPDATE: This has now been solved by the autor of jHtmlArea, [according to this closed bug](http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/workitem/15990).

Comment: use the jQuery migrate plugin http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/04/jquery-1-9-1-released/

Comment: @wirey They seem to have done a good job. I'm going to do that unless the original author of jHtmlArea fixes the cause for this.

Comment: @wirey I have good succes, doing as you mentioned, and not found any related problem. Please post as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery migrate for backwards compatibility, and it will show you in the console what needs to be fixed to be up to date with jQuery 1.9+.

From the docs http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/04/jquery-1-9-1-released/

```
Please, please, please, use the jQuery Migrate plugin and look at the upgrade guide if you’re just
starting your upgrade to jQuery 1.9. The plugin will quickly find and fix any compatibility issues,
just look in the browser console. Once you fix the warnings you can remove it. Or, leave the plugin in
place until you have the chance to fix your code and plugins to make them 1.9-compatible.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they released a new version of JHtmlArea that fixed the problem.

https://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/downloads/get/832017